# python postgresql ms access driver advice

Tags: python, postgresql, ms-access, psycopg2, pyodbc

We are building a datawarehouse in PostgreSQL. We want to connect to different data sources. Most data will come from ms access. We not not python experts (yet :-)).
We found several database connectors. We want to use (as much as possible) standard SQL for our queries.
We looked at pyodbc pscopg2.
Given that we use MS Access and PostgreSQL and want to have the same query syntax and return data types; Which drivers should we use ?

Comment: Not used it myself, but might be worth spending an hour seeing if the odbc fdw will handle what you need - you can do all your importing from PostgreSQL then http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#odbc_fdw

Answer (score 1):

Your query syntax differences will depend on PostgreSQL extensions vs MS Access-specific quirks.  The psycodb and pyodbc will both provide a query interface using whatever SQL dialect (with quirks) the underlying db connections provide.